# What does 'ICU' stand for in Android SDK?

Tags: java, android, package, icu

Have seen new packages in Android SDK docs. All of them are available in API level 24 which corresponds to Android Nougat and seem to replace the '*java.xxx*' packages by '*android.icu.xxx*'. For example:

> The *java.text.DateFormat* package is duplicated in *android.icu.text.DateFormat* and so on

Also, in some icu classes appears the following annotation:

> [icu enhancement] ICU's replacement for (class name). Methods, fields, and other functionality specific to ICU are labeled '[icu]'.

So, what does ICU stand for? And what are differences between java and android.icu packages? Will java packages be deprecated soon?

Comment: [International Components for Unicode](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/icu4j-framework.html)

Comment: This library can be [quite large](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28241755/3681880) to include in your project pre-API 24.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[This](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/icu4j-framework.html) explains the notion of `icu` pretty well. They've basically introduced this for the later API's to "reduce your APK footprint". I don't think that the ICU is a replacement for the `java.*.*` libraries but is just an alternative to use. There is also one interesting thing on that page:

> As the ICU team deprecates APIs in the future, Android will also mark them as deprecated but will continue to include them.

[Here](http://site.icu-project.org/home/why-use-icu4j) is also a little list of features about ICU4J which is quite helpful.

Comment: I have found that the java.text.SimpleDateFormat in my current builds is behaving like the ICU implementation, despite documentation to the contrary,  Confusing. Android Studio 3.5.3 target SDK 28.

Answer (score 16):

ICU stands for International Components for Unicode

http://site.icu-project.org/