# BreakIterator not working correctly with Chinese text

Tags: java, chinese-locale, breakiterator

I used BreakIterator.getWordInstance to split a Chinese text into words. Here is my example

```java
import java.text.BreakIterator;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Sample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String stringToExamine = "I like to eat apples. 我喜欢吃苹果。";

        //print each word in order
        BreakIterator boundary = BreakIterator.getWordInstance(new Locale("zh", "CN"));
        boundary.setText(stringToExamine);

        printEachForward(boundary, stringToExamine);
    }

    public static void printEachForward(BreakIterator boundary, String source) {
        int start = boundary.first();
        for (int end = boundary.next(); end != BreakIterator.DONE; start = end, end = boundary.next()) {
            System.out.println(start + ": " + source.substring(start, end));
        }
    }
}
```

My example text is taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/42219474/954439

The output that I get is

```
0: I
1:  
2: like
6:  
7: to
9:  
10: eat
13:  
14: apples
20: .
21:  
22: 我喜欢吃苹果
28: 。
```

Whereas, the expected output is

```
0 I
1  
2 like
6  
7 to
9  
10 eat
13  
14 apples
20 .
21  
22 我
23 喜欢
25 吃
26 苹果
28 。
```

I even tried pure Chinese text, but the words are broken on whitespace and punctuation characters.

I am programming for a server, so the jar file size is not a big concern. I am trying to find the number of words that is different in a given content compared to a sample content using Least Common Subsequence (but on words).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Suragch I am programming for a server, so the jar file size is not a big concern. I am trying to find the number of words that is different in a given content compared to a sample content using Least Common Subsequence (but on words).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard `BreakIterator` does not support detection of "word" boundaries within unbroken strings of CJK ideographs. There is a [bug report](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4095325) on this subject, but it was closed in 2006 as "Won't Fix".

Instead, you'll need to use the [ICU implementation](http://userguide.icu-project.org/boundaryanalysis). If you're developing on Android, you already have this as `android.icu.text.BreakIterator`. Otherwise, you'll need to download the ICU4J library from http://site.icu-project.org/download, which has it as `com.ibm.icu.text.BreakIterator`.

Comment: I wonder how it worked for the person who answered https://stackoverflow.com/a/42219474/954439 . I was also seeing other sites that claim that BreakIterator works with Chinese text.

Comment: @srgsanky It appears that answer’s code is running in Android, which has a different BreakIterator implementation.

Comment: Updated my answer, there's an alternate implementation that works.

Comment: @srgsanky, Although I was programming for Android, I was specifically using the Java BreakIterator and not the ICU version because the ICU version was not supported until Android API version 24 and I needed to support earlier devices. It is possible to include the ICU jar but it is rather large so I decided against it. (But see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28241755/icu4j-is-too-big-any-alternative).) This may be a viable option for you, though.

Comment: There probably is something about the Android version of the Java [BreakIterator](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/BreakIterator.html) as opposed to the ICU [BreakIterator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/icu/text/BreakIterator.html) that made it work for me.